# Constructing a non-vanishing vector field on $M \times S^1$, $M$ manifold $S^1$ the circle.

Tags: manifolds

The title pretty much says it all. How do I go about constructing a non-vanishing vector field on $M\times S^1$ where $M$ is a manifold and $S^1$ the circle? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the vector field $(0, 1)$. Here $1$ means the unit tangent vector on the circle.